# Spring Web vs Spring Rest Repositories

Tags: spring, spring-boot

It's not very clear to me what is the difference between the options below in https://start.spring.io/ *select dependencies* fields

> Web - 
>   Full-stack web development with Tomcat and Spring MVC
>
> Rest Repositories -
>   Expressing Spring Data repositories over REST via
>   spring-data-rest-webmvc

The way I see it, **Rest Repositories** is pure backend dependencies..

I want to create( learn ) a spring project that has an endpoint to specify for a webhook consumption and can send HTTP request to APIs after doing some backend processing

Comment: Use web.  You will just need spring mvc.  If you need persistance you can add spring data.  You don't need spring data rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference for spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-data-rest for REST APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914752/difference-for-spring-boot-starter-web-and-spring-boot-starter-data-rest-for-res)

Answer (score 1):

What I understood is (in lame terms), *Rest Repositories* enable Spring to automatically add *"our so-called Controller specific code"* & allows developers to skip adding them for simple purposes.

e.g. [this page](https://progressivecoder.com/exposing-repositories-as-rest-resources-using-spring-boot/) here shows how easy it would be for us to directly query a DB without adding own API & Service layers.

Spring did it all for us. Plus it also added configurations to override them if we want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of this [page](https://progressivecoder.com/exposing-repositories-as-rest-resources-using-spring-boot/), Spring Data Rest adds some abstraction to your code. Basically, all you need to do is create the repository, and Spring does all the black magic. It also includes [HATEOAS](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html), which is considered a good practice in API design for navigating through the endpoints.

However, this may not be ideal for production code. Spring Web (MVC), on the other hand, gives you more power to implement a robust API. For example, you can use DTO classes to restrict the response for the client and build a service layer that handles the business logic.

Answer (score -3):

Never used [spring data rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/) but it look that it's main purpose is to make rest webservice over a datasource. I think this is limited.

So you should go with a Web full stack. 
You can still do REST with it, and if you don't want view, just return json or anything.