# Difference for spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-data-rest for REST APIs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to figure out the best practise in Spring to develop a REST API.

I found those two packages and as far as I understand the difference between them is:

- web supports other things on top of REST API
- web manages resource access via controllers
- data-rest manages resource access via the repository

Is there anything that I'm missing? Most examples are on top of web so I wonder what decisions points would lead me to favor one over the other in my app.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed, and the rampant closing of questions is one of the things that bothers me the most about SO. The user isn't asking for opinions, but about the differences between the two packages. The differences are a matter of fact. The use cases might verge somewhat into opinion and preference, but precluding ANY mention of personal practices in responses is both impossible and counterproductive. To me, this question seems to point out a valid need for clarification is an acceptable topic to address.

Comment: -data-rest is based on -web and long story short add @RepositoryRestResource to implement Spring HATEOAS over jpa

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well it depends on what you want. Both are -web- **starters** (they make easy to add jars to your classpath) that will help you make a **REST API**, but *data-rest* has a more specific purpose, it help you to expose repositories as a **REST** services (In fact if you see their **pom.xml**, *data-rest* depends on *stater-web*). If that is what you want, voila! But if you want more control over the data, controllers, validation or project structure, *stater-web* is your option.

Comment: so what's add -data-rest over -web?

Comment: Can u please elaborate the answer little more and in specific?

Comment: @AlessandroScarozza 

```<dependency>

      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>


      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>


      <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>


      <scope>compile</scope>


    </dependency>


    <dependency>


      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>


      <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>```

Comment: @AlessandroScarozza, and also, check out this link. 
[link]https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro